# Base size in postgresql shows different values, how it fix?

Tags: postgresql

queries show different values, how to fix this?

```
 postgres=# SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('report') );
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 **134 GB**
(1 row)
```

Second request:

```
select table_name, pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) )
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) desc
```

result:

```
"zinc_source_bind"  "188 MB"
"zinc_blob_bind"    "122 MB"
"zinc_agent_info_ex"    "121 MB"
"zinc_blob" "110 MB"
"zinc_main" "86 MB"
"zinc_attribs_bind" "49 MB"
"zinc_not_readed"   "47 MB"
"zinc_aggregate_info"   "46 MB"
"zinc_gate" "39 MB"
"zinc_source"   "2488 kB"
```

how do I find out why it shows different results?

Answer (score 0):

`pg_relation_size` shows the size of the table without indexes and TOAST tables. If you use `pg_total_relation_size`, the gap should be smaller.